# Error when starting gitk

Tags: git, gitk

When starting gitk on command line im getting the following error:

```
user@comp:~/gitfolder$ gitk
Error in startup script: bad geometry specifier "1x-29"
    while executing
"wm geometry . "${w}x$h""
    (procedure "makewindow" line 401)
    invoked from within
"makewindow"
    (file "/usr/bin/gitk" line 12258)
```

Im running Ubuntu 14.04. This problem only happens with gitk (for example git gui works normally). I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling gitk (and git in general) but the problem still exists.

Comment: please reinstall git and its dependencies

Comment: Problem still exists, tried uninstalling git and its dependancies using apt-get remove --auto-remove git and then reinstalling git and gitk but the same error appears

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, I addressed it by opening the .gitk in an editor, and removing the following line:

```
set geometry(main) 1x-29+-1930+14
```

Alternatively, deleting the .gitk file from your home directory should also work.

Comment: adding that entry did not solve the problem for me, but deleting the gitk file removed the problem. The file was not in the home-directory directly, but in ~/.config/git/gitk

Comment: might also be in ~/.gitk

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is very old, but I've encountered the same problem (accidentally pressed to me an unknown combination of keys) and maybe my solution can be helpful to someone.

1. Open the config file in the .git folder of a project (PROJECT/.git/config).
2. In the [gui] section, remove the geometry option.
3. Restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ubuntu 17.04, and my gitk file is in "~/.config/git/gitk",

Deleting this line ===> "set geometry(main) 1x-29*****"   works for my ;)